# Homeomorphisms between infinite-dimensional Banach spaces and their spheres

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology

As I know Cz. Bessaga has proved that an infinite-dimensional Banach space is homeomorphic to its unit sphere.
Unfortunately I do not have his book but I want to know is this theorem true without dependence from that the space is separable or not, and it is real or complex.

That is, is it true that:

i) a real separable infinite-dimensional Banach space is homeomorphic to its sphere;

ii) a complex separable infinite-dimensional Banach space is homeomorphic to its sphere;

iii) a real non-separable infinite-dimensional Banach space is homeomorphic to its sphere;

iv) a complex non-separable infinite-dimensional Banach space is homeomorphic to its sphere?

Please answer even a part of my questions, that you know precisely.

Comment: Crossposted on [MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/678214/homeomorphisms-between-infinite-dimensional-banach-spaces-and-their-spheres).

Comment: You do not need to bother about $\mathbb{C}$. A complex Banach space is a particular case of a real Banach space by restriction of the scalar field, and a homeomorphism is just about topology.

Comment: Not an answer but some references that might be helpful: Bessaga and Pelczynski penned a survey "Selected topics in infinite dimensional topology" and their work was continued to the non-separable case by H. Torunczyk and then by T. Banakh.  The latter's articles are available on arXiv.